# How to run @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite methods defined in another class before the execution of the step def class starts?

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, testng, bdd

Can someone explain why I am not able to run this cucumber, testng project? Below is the code:

```
TestRunner.java:
package runner;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = "steps",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/json-report/cucumber.json"},
        dryRun = false,
        monochrome = true
)

@Test
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}

GithubLoginPageSteps.java:
package steps;

import static org.testng.Assert.fail;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class GithubLoginPageSteps extends CommonSteps {
    private WebDriver driver;
    
    public GithubLoginPageSteps(CommonSteps commonSteps) {
        System.out.println("Inside CitiHomePageSteps() ");
        this.driver = commonSteps.getDriver();
    }
    
    @Given("I am on the {string}")
    public void i_am_on_the(String githubHomePageUrl) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(githubHomePageUrl);
        driver.get(githubHomePageUrl);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    @When("the user enters the right {string} and {string}")
    public void the_user_enters_the_right_and(String username, String pwd) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login_field\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login_field\"]")).sendKeys(username);
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).sendKeys(pwd);
    }
    @When("the user clicks on the sign on button")
    public void the_user_clicks_on_the_sign_on_button() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]/div[4]/form/div/input[12]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(000);
    }
    @Then("the user is navigated to the {string}")
    public void the_user_is_navigated_to_the(String githubDashboardUrl) {
       String actualUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
       String expectedUrl = githubDashboardUrl;
       System.out.println("Actual url is:"+ actualUrl);
       System.out.println("Expected url is:"+ expectedUrl);
       driver.quit();
       if(!actualUrl.equals(expectedUrl)) {
           fail("Dashboard url didn't match the expected url:"+ expectedUrl);
       }
    }
}

CommonSteps.java:
package steps;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;

public class CommonSteps {
private WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/webdriver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("Inside @BeforeSuite hook");
    }
    
    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        System.out.println("Inside @AfterSuite hook");
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        System.out.println("Inside getDriver()");
        return this.driver;
    }
}

testng.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
      <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
          <class name="runner.TestRunner"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->

pom.xml:

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.shri.automation</groupId>
        <artifactId>Cucumber-TestNg2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
        <name>Cucumber-TestNg2</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.10.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                <version>6.10.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-beta-4</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.10.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/masterthought-report</outputDirectory>
                                <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/json-report/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>

GithubLoginFeaturePage.feature:
Feature: Github Login Page 

Scenario Outline: Github Login
Given I am on the '<GithubLoginPage_url>'
When the user enters the right '<username>' and '<password>'
And the user clicks on the sign on button
Then the user is navigated to the '<Github_dashboard_url>'

Examples:
|GithubLoginPage_url|username|password|Github_dashboard_url|
|https://github.com/login|abc@gmail.com|1234|https://github.com/|
```

[Project structure link][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAFom.png

The error I get is:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null
at steps.GithubLoginPageSteps.i_am_on_the(GithubLoginPageSteps.java:27)

Comment: Because I wanted to store the reference of the driver(so that I can use it in the GithubLoginPageSteps.java) that I would be getting from the CommonSteps.java which is where I am actually initializing the driver.

Comment: Change `driver` variable scope to `public` in `CommonSteps`.

Comment: Why to change the access modifier of driver in CommonSteps to public when I have a getter method for driver in CommonSteps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason why that 'driver is null error' was coming in the GithubLoginPageSteps. Because in the testng.xml file I forgot to add the  inside the  of the  named 'Test'. And then I need to make the 'driver' variable in CommonSteps as static so that the same copy is used across all instances of the CommonSteps class.

This is necessary because two instances of the CommonSteps would be created when I now run the testng.xml file, one to run the CommonSteps.java class defined in the testng.xml where the 'driver' would be initialized and then in the GithubLoginSteps.java I am also injecting the CommonSteps class instance using the cucumber picocontainer and then use this to get the 'driver'. So you see if I don't declare the driver as static then there is no way 'driver' would be initialized in the CommonSteps.java and it would remain as null.

Also I found that I don't even need to extend the CommonSteps class inside the GithubLoginPageSteps class and the thread-count attribute in the testng.xml is also redundant.

With these changes I tried to run the code and it worked!